# Politeness / political correctness and gender polarity of "plural" suffix -等(ら) for 彼 and 彼女 etc

Tags: pronouns, plurals

The definitions on ejje.weblio:

- [彼ら](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BD%BC%E3%82%89)
- [彼女ら](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%BD%BC%E5%A5%B3%E3%82%89)

What I would like to know is:

1. 彼ら is definitely gender neutral and 彼女ら can only have females in the group, right?
2. As explained in [Why is “学生” made “plural” in this newspaper article?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23476/why-is-%E5%AD%A6%E7%94%9F-made-plural-in-this-newspaper-article), adding -ら allows for a more precise statement. But I wonder, do they sound impolite and rough and would not be used in newspapers?
3. Is 彼ら rarely used in speaking? And  never in writing?
4. Is 彼女ら just *never* used?
5. Is あいつら not uncommon, but used in extremely informal conversations?
6. You cannot substitute たち for ら and say 彼たち, 彼女たち, or あいつたち, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 彼ら is definitely gender neutral and 彼女ら can only have females in the group, right?

If you think using *he* in English when the gender is unknown is politically incorrect, then you would still want to worry about 彼ら a bit, too. You don't have to be too strict, but avoiding gender-neutral 彼ら when possible is a good habit.

And I think the singular 彼 strongly indicates the male gender, perhaps even more strongly than English *he*.

> Adding -ら allows for a more precise statement. But I wonder, do they sound impolite and rough and would not be used in newspapers?

彼ら and 彼女ら are used both in formal and casual situations. There's nothing impolite.

> Is 彼ら rarely used in speaking? And never in writing?
>   Is 彼女ら just never used?

They are used both in casual speaking and writing, but not as frequently as he/she/they is used in English. Repeating the original noun (e.g. 学生たち, その人たち, 山田さんたち), or simply omitting such pronouns, is the preferred way in Japanese.

> Is あいつら not uncommon, but used in extremely informal conversations?

あいつら (as well as こいつら, そいつら) is more than just informal; it's rough, and frequently (not always) used in derogatory sentences. I would never use あいつ(ら) unless I'm really upset.

> You cannot substitute たち for ら and say 彼たち, 彼女たち, or あいつたち, right?

彼ら, 彼女ら and 彼女たち are all commonly used, but 彼たち is extremely uncommon for some reason. I don't know why. But you can check [this article](http://www.ytv.co.jp/blog/announcers/michiura/2009/12/post-69.html).

Comment: Perhaps better asked as another question, but addressing your first point: what is the proper thing to say when you need to make the subject clear, and the gender is unknown (for both singular and plural amounts of people)? あの人(たち)?

Comment: @Eric It's difficult to explain, but you can see real examples like [this one](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9C%8B%E8%AD%B7%E5%B8%AB), where no 彼/彼女 is used in the main text. あの人たち may sound impolite.

Comment: I'd rather say かれたち etc are not a word. 
I think it's because 彼・われ are a true pronoun that they don't take たち except when 彼 means boyfriend.

Answer (score 1):

> 彼ら is definitely gender neutral and 彼女ら can only have females in the group, right?

Japanese plurals are (or at least can be) associative. 彼ら means "he and the ones I/we associate with him", just like 田中たち doesn't necessarily designate a group where everybody is called Tanaka, but means "Tanaka and the ones associated with him/her". So 彼ら would usually have a male representative, and 彼女ら would have a female representative. Not everybody would have to be female. See previous question here: [What rules should be followed when saying "we"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5844/what-rules-should-be-followed-when-saying-we/5850#5850)

> You cannot substitute たち for ら and say 彼たち, 彼女たち, or あいつたち, right?

たち and ら are both quite productive (i.e. you can attach them to almost all kinds of animate nouns/pronouns), but ら has an affectionate/derogatory nuance:

広辞苑･･･ら[等]
①体言の下について複数を表す。
②人を表す名詞や代名詞に付いて、**親愛・謙譲・蔑視**の気持ちを表す。

彼ら is an exception, since as @naruto says, 彼たち is uncommon. Also, あいつたち is, I guess, possible, but sounds strange, since あいつ already has affection/derogation built in and therefore goes better with ら.